# How to generate a random order of numbers to a string based on conditions Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, random

How would you generate a random number string in Python based on the following conditions.

1. The string must be between the length of 3 and 7
2. The string must only contain numbers from 1-7
3. The string must not have spaces

I tried the following for the string output but I am struggling with the conditionals

```
letters = string.digits
print ( ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10)) )
```

The output I received was:=

```
9432814671
```

If you could be kind enough to help me out and guide me I would be grateful to you.

Comment: The third requirement is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is self-explanatory, and you were close to it:

```
length = random.randint(3, 7)
"".join(str(random.randint(1, 7)) for _ in range(length))
#'724613'
```

Comment: Respected Sir, 
Thank you for your time.
Forgive me, I am new to Python and still learning.